# JqPlot erro no IE 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, jquery

Estou utilizando o plugin `JqPlot` para gerar um gráfico de barras e colunas. Após efetuar os testes no Mozilla e no Chrome, que funcionou perfeitamente, realizei o teste no `IE7` e no `IE8` e obtive o seguinte erro:

> window.g_vmlcanvasmanager is null or not an object.

Alguém sabe me dizer por quê? Pois importei todas as bibliotecas necessárias, inclusive as do `Canvas`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Versões desatualizadas do jqPlot não funcionam com o jQuery 1.9](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/710/compatibility-with-jquery-v19)

Atualize a versão do jqPlot que está usando, ou use uma versão anterior do jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternativamente, inclua o jQuery migrate: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

---

É importante lembrar que o **jQuery versão 2** não oferece mais suporte às versões antigas do IE.

---

Além disso, para dar suporte a IE menor do que 9, também é necessário o código condicional abaixo (você disse que já incluiu isso, mas fica aqui a título de completude):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Fonte: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html

Comment: Estou utilizando o Jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Ok. Pesquisei mais; por favor, veja a resposta atualizada.

Comment: Grato pela resposta, utilizando o jquery 1.8 passou a funcionar no IE 8.